# How much memory is needed to run a Minecraft Server in 1.6.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server

What is a reasonable amount of RAM needed to run a Minecraft server?

I've already tried running a server with 256MB. However, within an hour, the server was crashing due to being out of memory.